# Extra space showing up next to content

Tags: html, css, wordpress, slider, padding

http://stanleyjoseph.co/mct/artful-mix-2/ is the page in question.

I've tried removing the padding from .styleparagraph and .styledescription but that doesnt seem to do anything. Could a more seasoned developer lend me some advice?

```
.styleparagraph {
padding: 0 15px;
}

.styledescription {
padding: 15px;
line-height: 2.5em;
}
```

[image: example 1]

[image: example 2]

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **overflow: hidden;** CSS property to solve this.

```
.styleparagraph {
padding: 0 15px;
overflow: hidden;
}

.styledescription {
padding: 15px;
line-height: 2.5em;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

This seems to fix your problem. Hope this fixes your problem.

Comment: at first I thought this had solved the problem but I'm seeing now on mobile (or if you shrink the browser) the problem persists. Any suggestions?